# Is there a way of generating asm code in a .S file using C macros?

Tags: c, assembly

I have to generate redundant asm code which keeps calling different C functions

i am trying to do something like

```
#define CODE_GEN(func) push a \
         call func
         pop a
```

invoking something like

```
CODE_GEN(foo)
```

will generate

```
bash-4.1$ gcc -E mk.S 
# 1 "mk.S"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "mk.S"
# 1 "asm_gen.h" 1
# 2 "mk.S" 2
# 13 "mk.S"
pusha call foo popa iret
```

but this fails in compilation

```
bash-4.1$ gcc -m32 mk.S 
mk.S: Assembler messages:
mk.S:13: Error: junk `foo popa iret' after expression
mk.S:13: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pusha'
```

is there a way to delimit asm code written in a single line in a .S file ?

Comment: Instead of generating an assembly file, why not generate a file with a function containing inline assembly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I dont want to use inline assemble because I have been told that inline assembly code is not portable across various platform and assemblers.I am inclined to use a .S file over inline assembly

Comment: The non-inline assembly is just as (non-)portable as the inline assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

semicolons ';' can be used in place of line breaks.

So something like

```
#define CODE_GEN(func) push a; \
call func; \
pop a;
```

will compile and work

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by using semicolons, see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22138675/1717300). C macros expand to a single string with no line breaks, but semicolons get around that.

You can also use [GNU Assembler macros](http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/Macro.html). This is totally untested, could be wrong:

```
.macro CODEGEN func
push a
call \func
pop a
.endm
```